# why is this jquery selector not selecting textarea?

Tags: jquery-selectors

in the following, I am using filter('input:text,textarea') to set input fields as read only, (and make them opaque). However, this selector is selecting only the text inputs, and not the textarea. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>setReadOnly() Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles/core.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.setReadOnly.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-1.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jqia2.support.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
          $.fn.setReadOnly = function(readonly) {
            return this.filter('input:text,textarea')
              .attr('readOnly',readonly)
              .css('opacity', readonly ? 0.5 : 1.0)
              .end();
          };
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        $('#sameAddressControl').click(function(){
          var same = this.checked;
          $('#billAddress').val(same ? $('#shipAddress').val():'');
          $('#billCity').val(same ? $('#shipCity').val():'');
          $('#billState').val(same ? $('#shipState').val():'');
          $('#billZip').val(same ? $('#shipZip').val():'');
          $('#bill_random_field').val(same ? $('#ship_random_field').val():'');
          $('#billingAddress input').setReadOnly(same);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div data-module="Test setReadOnly()">

      <form name="testForm">
        <div>
          <label>First name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Last name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName"/>
        </div>
        <div id="shippingAddress">
          <h2>Shipping address</h2>
          <div>
            <label>Street address:</label>
            <input type="text" name="shipAddress" id="shipAddress"/>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>City, state, zip, random_field:</label>
            <input type="text" name="shipCity" id="shipCity"/>
            <input type="text" name="shipState" id="shipState"/>
            <input type="text" name="shipZip" id="shipZip"/>
            <textarea name="random_field" rows="2" cols="20" id="ship_random_field"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="billingAddress">
          <h2>Billing address</h2>
          <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="sameAddressControl"/>
            Billing address is same as shipping address
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Street address:</label>
            <input type="text" name="billAddress"
                   id="billAddress"/>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>City, state, zip, random_field:</label>
            <input type="text" name="billCity" id="billCity"/>
            <input type="text" name="billState" id="billState"/>
            <input type="text" name="billZip" id="billZip"/>
            <textarea name="random_field" rows="2" cols="20" id="bill_random_field"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the line `$('#billingAddress input').setReadOnly(same);` to `$('#billingAddress input,textarea').setReadOnly(same);`

**Update**

Actually, must be like you said in the comment: `$('#billingAddress input,#billingAddress textarea')`.

Comment: interesting, that didn't work but changing it to          `$('#billingAddress input,#billingAddress textarea').setReadOnly(same);` did work. I am puzzled why your suggestion didn't work.

Comment: Suggestion didn't work because you are trying to filter the element itself, not the content. Instead you could try `$('#billingAddress').find('*').setReadOnly(same)`, or rewrite your filter to do `this.find('*')..`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put `input,textarea`